# Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript Error

Tags: yii

After looking around, I found out I have a problem with all my js that uses `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript`. It gives me `undefined is not a function` for yiigridview.

So I thought okay, yiigridview is the problem. But when I isolate everything line by line, I found that `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript` throws the error.

Heres an example - After my cgridview I have the following, and when I remove this block, error is gone.

```
<?php 
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('read', "
    $('#inbox a.read').live('click', function() {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('inbox', {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    success: function() {
                    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('inbox');
                    }
            });
            return false;
    });
    ");
    ?>
```

Comment: `undefined is not a function` is a javascript error, so `registerScript` can't throw this error, because it is a php function. So I would guess that a part of `$.fn.yiiGridView.update('inbox');` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript that happens if the CGridView "#inbox" is not present in the DOM when the  `$.fn.yiiGridView.update('inbox')` call is triggered .

The problem is you are calling calling `$.fn.yiiGridView.update('inbox');`  twice; remove the second call and the `success` function, there is no need to refresh grid in middle of a refresh, this error should be fixed.

Comment: Try loading your script in the end; use CClientScript::POS_END as the third argument after the second argument in registerScript.